# Automatic update of select-table sql (trigger)

Tags: mysql, select, triggers, insert-update

I am developing a small database of a a school, using MySQL.
I have a table for professors, with id, name and email, and a table for lectures,with id, name of lecture, and the edition of that class. Then, I have an intermediary table for both professors and lectures.

As you can see bellow my last table includes a column for evaluation. Where, for each lecture a professor receives a score.

```
  CREATE TABLE professor ( 
professor_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
professor_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE);

CREATE TABLE lecture (
lecture_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
lecture_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
edition INT NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE lecture_prof (
professor_id INT,
lecture_id INT,
Evaluation INT,
FOREIGN KEY (professor_id) REFERENCES professor (professor_id),
FOREIGN KEY (lecture_id) REFERENCES lecture (lecture_id));
```

Now, I want the average evaluations of all the classes that the professors lectures. And I created a table with select.

```
   CREATE TABLE Avg_Evaluation AS SELECT 
p.professor_id,p.professor_name, AVG(Evaluation) AS Avg_Eval
    FROM professor p, lecture_professor lp
    WHERE p.professor_id=lp.professor_id
    GROUP BY professor_id, professor_name;
```

The table works but it has a problem, the only values it show are values that are already in the parents table (lecture_professor) before the table Avg_evaluation is created. And If I want to add new professors and new editions the table does not update automatically.

How can I solve this? I also thought I could do an updatedable view but I cannot use the arithmetic functions like AVG.

I wanted to do a trigger, for after inserting any new values on the lecture_professor table. but I don't know how.

Thank you for your help!

EDIT: here are some dummy values. and corrections.

```
    INSERT INTO faculty 
VALUES
(1,'Ana ','as@email.com'), 
(2,'Peter','pt@email.com'),
(3,'Mitchel','mm@email.org');

INSERT INTO lecture VALUES (1, 'Econ', 20),(2, 'History', 1),(3, 'Social Studies', 2);

INSERT INTO lecture_professor VALUES (1,1,3),(2,1,2),(2,2,4),(2,3,4),(1,3,2),(3,1,3);
```

Comment: Some code criticism - 1) Distinct with a group by is pointless since the group by will return 1 row per p.professor_id,p.professor_name anyway 2) Group by should include both selected columns p.professor_id,p.professor_name 3) Use explicit rather than implicit joins 4) It's not generally a good idea to create a table for something which can be calculated , and in this case could cause maintenance issues if the avg is subject to change as it will be if a professor accrues more lectures.

Comment: @P.Salmon Thank you for your suggestions, I will apply them. But I don't understand the 3. And also, how could I solve my problem if creating a table is not the best idea?

Comment: Sure, Add some sample data to your question as text.

Comment: @P.Salmon I laid some example values as code (It was easier since I am testing a few options at the moment with those). Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your data with a view

```
drop table if exists lecture_professor;
drop table if exists lecture,professor;

CREATE TABLE professor ( 
professor_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
professor_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE);

CREATE TABLE lecture (
lecture_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
lecture_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
edition INT NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE lecture_professor (
professor_id INT,
lecture_id INT,
Evaluation INT ,
FOREIGN KEY fk1 (professor_id) REFERENCES professor (professor_id),
FOREIGN KEY fk2 (lecture_id) REFERENCES lecture (lecture_id)
);

insert into professor values
(1,'Ana ','as@email.com'), 
(2,'Peter','pt@email.com'),
(3,'Mitchel','mm@email.org');

INSERT INTO lecture VALUES (1, 'Econ', 20),(2, 'History', 1),(3, 'Social Studies', 2);

INSERT INTO lecture_professor VALUES (1,1,3),(2,1,2),(2,2,4),(2,3,4),(1,3,2),(3,1,3);

drop view if exists v;
create view v as 
SELECT p.professor_id,p.professor_name, 
        coalesce(AVG(Evaluation),0) AS Avg_Eval
FROM professor p
left join lecture_professor lp on p.professor_id = lp.professor_id
GROUP BY professor_id,p.professor_name
; 

select * from v;
```

I don't know why you don't think a view cannot contain an aggregate function because the output looks fine to me

```
+--------------+----------------+----------+
| professor_id | professor_name | Avg_Eval |
+--------------+----------------+----------+
|            1 | Ana            |   2.5000 |
|            2 | Peter          |   3.3333 |
|            3 | Mitchel        |   3.0000 |
+--------------+----------------+----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Please note the explicit join.

Comment: Because I read that an updatable view could not have an arithmetic function here: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/create-sql-updatable-views.aspx . But I added new values to the lecture_professor table and the view did update the new values, except the avg. which returned zero. here are the new values I used: `
insert into professor values
(4,'Mitchaela','mma@email.org');

INSERT INTO lecture VALUES (4, 'Spanish', 2);

select * from v; `

Comment: You are correct that updateable views cannot contain a group by , I would argue that the view does not have to be updateable.

Comment: An avg of 0 for Mitchaela is correct this professor does not have any evaluations - what did you expect the avg to be.

Comment: You are right! That works, I just had a small mistake in my code. Thank you very much for your input!

Comment: Exactly I forgot to add the values for the evaluation. Sorry!

Comment: Might I just ask, why do you use coalesce before the average function?

Comment: I prefer to see 0 rather than null, you don't need to use coalesce if your preference is the reverse

Answer (score 0):

What you need is after insert [trigger](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html) you can find syntax below

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name
AFTER INSERT
   ON table_name FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

   -- variable declarations

   -- trigger code

END;
```

Example:-

```
CREATE TRIGGER new_loaner_added 
AFTER INSERT ON total_loaner
FOR EACH ROW 
  INSERT INTO available_loaner (Kind, Type, Sno, Status)
  VALUES (NEW.Kind, NEW.Type, NEW.Sno, 'Available');
```

Comment: Thank you, and can you help me with the code for this particular scenario?